Increasing sequence of integers
Can I have an increasing sequence of positive integers $p_n$ such that $$\liminf\frac{p_n}{n}\neq\limsup\frac{p_n}{n},$$ or even with the former being finite and the latter infinite?
(For context, I'm trying to understand to statement of Pólya's theorem and why the theorem uses $\liminf$ instead of $\lim$, since $p_n/n$ has a limit – or not? Similarly with the statement of this Erdős's problem.)

Well, if the limit exists, then the lim inf and the lim sup agree with it.  Sometimes, a theorem's condition(s) is(are) stated in terms of lim inf or lim sup, which always exist, instead of the limit, which may or may not exist and thus requires more work to apply the theorem.

If the $p_n$ sequence is strictly increasing then $0<n \le p_n $ so $1\le \liminf\frac{p_n}{n} \le  \limsup\frac{p_n}{n}$; you could have $\liminf\frac{p_n}{n}=1$ and $\limsup\frac{p_n}{n}=\infty$, or  $\liminf\frac{p_n}{n}=\limsup\frac{p_n}{n}=1$, or  $\liminf\frac{p_n}{n}=\limsup\frac{p_n}{n}=\infty$, or anything less extreme than that.  If the $p_n$ sequence is weakly increasing you could have $\liminf\frac{p_n}{n}=0$ and $\limsup\frac{p_n}{n}=\infty$, or  $\liminf\frac{p_n}{n}=\limsup\frac{p_n}{n}=0$, or  $\liminf\frac{p_n}{n}=\limsup\frac{p_n}{n}=\infty$, or anything less extreme.

@Henry Can you provide an example of increasing positive integers $p_n$ such that $\liminf p_n/n\neq\limsup p_n/n$, please?

@byk7 such a sequence added in an answer.  It starts $1,2,3,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,$ $20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,$ $30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,108,109, \ldots$

If the $p_n$ sequence is strictly increasing then $0<n \le p_n $ so $1\le \liminf\frac{p_n}{n} \le  \limsup\frac{p_n}{n}$; you could have

$\liminf\frac{p_n}{n}=1$ and $\limsup\frac{p_n}{n}=\infty$,
or  $\liminf\frac{p_n}{n}=\limsup\frac{p_n}{n}=1$,
or  $\liminf\frac{p_n}{n}=\limsup\frac{p_n}{n}=\infty$,
or anything less extreme than thse.

If the $p_n$ sequence is weakly increasing you could have

$\liminf\frac{p_n}{n}=0$ and $\limsup\frac{p_n}{n}=\infty$,
or  $\liminf\frac{p_n}{n}=\limsup\frac{p_n}{n}=0$,
or  $\liminf\frac{p_n}{n}=\limsup\frac{p_n}{n}=\infty$,
or anything less extreme.

As an example of $\liminf\frac{p_n}{n}=1$ and $\limsup\frac{p_n}{n}=\infty$ with a strictly increasing sequence, consider
$$p_{(k!)^2} = k(k!)^2 \text{ including }p_1=1, \, \, p_n=p_{n-1}+1 \text{ otherwise}$$
Then by construction $\dfrac{p_{(k!)^2}}{(k!)^2}=k$, so $\limsup\frac{p_n}{n}=\infty$,
while $\dfrac{p_{(k!)^2-1}}{(k!)^2-1} = \frac{(k-1)((k-1)!)^2 +(k!)^2-1-((k-1)!)^2}{(k!)^2-1} \le 1 + \frac1k$, so $\liminf\frac{p_n}{n}=1$.
For example, looking at $k=8$, you get $p_{1625702399}=1778111999$ and $\frac{1778111999}{1625702399} \approx 1.09375000006$ while the next term is $p_{1625702400}=13005619200$ and $\frac{13005619200}{1625702400} =8$.

Great, in fact I played with very similar example $p_{k^2}=k^3$ and $p_n=p_{n-1}+1$ otherwise. But I failed to make the correct conclusion because I messed up with indices and subsequences... -_-

Note that if $f(x)=xg(x)$ then $f'(x)=g(x)+xg'(x)$
We want this derivative positive (i.e $p_n$ increasing) but $g$ oscillating to have $\varliminf\neq\varlimsup$
If we take $g(x)=\sin(\text{something})$ the $x$ before $g'$ is annoying, since divergence to infinity kills the positivity condition (given that $g'$ sign changes).
So the idea is to take $\sin(\ln x)$ so that the $\frac 1x$ coming from the log cancels with the one before $g'(x)$.
Now since $|\sin(u)+\cos(u)|=|\sqrt{2}\sin(u+\pi/4)|\le\sqrt{2}\ $ we can shift the whole thing by $2$ to ensure positivity of $f'(x)$

Therefore I propose $f(x)=x\cdot(2+\sin(\ln(x))$ and $p_n=f(n)$

And $\ \frac{p_n}{n}=2+\sin(\ln(n))\ $ has $\ \varliminf=1\ $ and $\ \varlimsup=3\ $ since the logarithm goes to infinity, so the sinus keeps oscillating.

Then $p_n$ is not a sequence of integers, it's easily fixed though by taking e.g. $p_n=\left\lceil n(5+2\sin\ln n)\right\rceil$, thx.

To get a concrete example where $p_n$ is a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers, you can define $p_n$ recursively.  Begin with $p_n=n^2$ for $n\leq 100$.  Let $n_0=100$.  For $n_0<n\leq 2^{p_{n_0}}$, define $p_n = p_{n_0} + n-n_0$.  This grows linearly.  Keep alternating between linear growth on long stretches and quadratic growth on long stretches.  Let $n_1=2^{p_{n_0}}$.  Define $p_n = p_{n_1} + (n-n_1)^2$ for $n_1<n\leq 2^{p_{n_1}}$.  Let $n_2 = 2^{p_{n_1}}$.  Continue alternating like this forever. Then
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{p_{n_{2k-1}}}{n_{2k-1}} = 1$$ and
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{p_{n_{2k}}}{n_{2k}} = \infty .$$
Therefore, the $\liminf = 1$ and the $\limsup = \infty$.
